# как запустить grunt из cron

Tags: gulp, npm, grunt

из папки проекта комманда вида:
grunt cssmin
запускается и сжимает css без проблем

код bash скрипта запускаемого из крон:

```
cd /var/www/project
# compress css
grunt cssmin
# compress jssudo 
gulp compress_js
```

при запуске bash скрипта из cron команды не выполняются.

Как запустить gulp(grunt) команды из cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставь полный путь до gulp(grunt).
Узнать можно с помощью `which grunt`

Answer (score 0):

```
root@ip-172-31-38-185 www]# which grunt
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin/grunt
[root@ip-172-31-38-185 www]# /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin/grunt cssmin
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

Comment: тогда официальные средства https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-crontab

Comment: возможно кто-то имел опыт запуска именно из cron ?

Answer (score 0):

По итогу решение следующее:

1. установлен пакет npm node-cron
2. написан скрипт cron.js

   #!/usr/bin/env node
      var cron = require('node-cron'),
          gulp = require('gulp'),
          uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
          pump = require('pump'),
          rename = require('gulp-rename'),
          cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');

   // gulp init
   gulp.task('compress_js', function (cb) {
       pump([
               gulp.src([
                   'scripts/**/*.js'
               ]),
               uglify(),
               // rename({suffix: ''}),
               gulp.dest('scripts/')
           ],
           cb
       );
   });

   gulp.task('compress_css', function () {
       gulp.src('css/**/*.css')
           .pipe(cssmin())
           // .pipe(rename({suffix: ''}))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
   });

   cron.schedule('1,16,31,46 * * * *', function(){
       // пережимаем compress
       gulp.start('compress_js');
       gulp.start('compress_css');

   ```
   console.log('start npm-cron script is successful');
   ```

   });
3. скрипт запускается через диспетчер процессов PM2 (так удобнее)